# Call a powershell script (on a network drive) from python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell

How do I call a powershell script from python but the ps script lies on a network drive?

Comment: It's better to put research effort into a question before you blindly ask here! :)

Comment: Not really, the thing is if I try to call the ps script from a Network drive, I am getting an error... or maybe im just doing it wrong :')

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include both the code you've tried and the error message you were getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("powershell \\path\to\script.ps1")
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that worked for me!